# (Storybook) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: storybook

I'm trying to run storybook test runner after installing it (being in nx environment):

```
npx test-storybook --url http://localhost:4400
```

And getting the error in the terminal:

```
[test-storybook] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

my storybook is running on `localhost:4400` and working properly, has anyone experienced this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that test-runner looks at the root `.storybook` directory.

If you have multiple dirs (for example due to the nx setup), you need to provide the exact storybook config directory against which you want to run the tests (for example, by providing the `--config-dir` option in your npm script).